# Fibonacci in python - Can some explain how this Fibonacci number between range works?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am learning python programming and i have run into a bit of jumble. I found this code to compute Fibonacci sequence by user inputted start and end number. Can someone explain how this code works?

```
def fib(lowerbound, upperbound):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    while x <= upperbound:
        if (x >= lowerbound):
            yield x
        x, y = y, x + y

startNumber = 10
endNumber = 100
for fib_sequence in fib(startNumber, endNumber):
    print "And the next number is... %d!" % fib_sequence
```

Comment: Voted to close as unclear what you're asking. "Explain every line in this code" is not an on-topic question. Should I start explaining what `x = 0` does?

Comment: It computes _all_ the fibonacci numbers up to upperbound but starts yielding only after numbers are greater then lowerbound. What's the question? How the `x, y = ...` line works? Or what `yield` does?

Comment: The basic loop should be pretty clear to you.  Now, pretend the `yield x` is instead `print x`.  Then it will clearly print the Fibonacci numbers between the lower and upper bounds, inclusive, right?  Ok, so what does the `yield` do?  It makes `fib` a generator, producing those same values one at a time as needed.  The result can be used anywhere an iterator is needed.  If this confuses you, then I suggest reading about generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `def fib( ...` returns a list on which you can iterate using `for i in <return val by fib>`

I guess your main confusion is around `yield` part. What it does is it remembers the past values (ie val of `x` and `y`) and next time it continues from previous values and whenever it sees `yield` it adds that yielded value (`x` here) to the returned list.

https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/

This article shall clear all your doubts.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you .. It clarifies my doubt.